# Search and replace some value with multiple random values

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, str-replace

I have a file with the following content.

> Some text bla-bla #date# other text #date# some other #date#

I need to replace #date# with some random date which I generate by using the following code with new random value for each #date#.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,45).' days'))
```

At the moment all dates are replaced with the same value.
Tks.

Comment: Sure, you need it identify all dates in the text file, iterate over them and replace them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to generate a new random date each time it replaces:

```
$string = 'Some text bla-bla #date# other text #date# some other #date#';
echo preg_replace_callback('/#date#/', function () { return date('Y-m-d', strtotime( '+'.mt_rand(0,45).' days')); }, $string);
```

Output:

```
Some text bla-bla 2019-01-22 other text 2019-02-16 some other 2019-02-19
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OSoWZu)